# JavaScript for toggling appearance

Tags: javascript, css, html5, dom

I have a dedicated stylesheet `<style id="dynamicStyles"></style>` for my page's dynamic styles. They are controlled by this JavaScript:

```
function style(className, sty) {
    var sheet = document.getElementById('dynamicStyles').sheet;
    sheet.insertRule('.' + className + ' {' + sty + '}');
}

// No validation, do not pass tainted content.
function unstyle(className, sty) {
    var sheet = document.getElementById('dynamicStyles').sheet;
    var rules = sheet.cssRules;
    var regex = new RegExp('\\.' + className);
    for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
        if (rules[i].cssText.match(regex)) {
            sheet.deleteRule(i);
            return;
        }
    }
}

function styleRule(className, that, sty) {
    if (that.checked) {
        style(className, sty);
    } else {
        unstyle(className);
    }
}
```

This is called, for example, like this:

```
<input type=checkbox onClick="styleRule('someClass', this, 'border: 1px #a00 dashed')">
```

There are maybe 10 or 20 inputs with similar code. The number of elements to be styled is large, hundreds or thousands, so I don't want to re-style each of them.

In addition to a general style review, I'm looking to see if there is a more elegant way to do the lookup in `unstyle`.

Comment: Why did you not use event listeners? Add class to each input, for example, `js-input`. Add `change` event (change is more suitable than `click` in this case). And write all logic in the handler. There is no need to add / remove styles. It is more elegant to add / remove classes. However, I can not help much while I do not see all you html. It is difficult to understand the purpose of your code for now.

Comment: @FreeLightman: I have about a thousand elements with the classes, and I don't want to change all of them each time the input is toggled. There's not much to see in the HTML, just a huge number of elements (350 kB).

Answer (score 4):

### Moar built-ins... MOAR (and a look-up table)!

**It is great** that you are using the built-in `insertRule` method for style sheets here:

> ```
> sheet.insertRule('.' + className + ' {' + sty + '}');
> ```

**It is *not* great** that you *aren't* using the built in [`deleteRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule) for style sheets here:

> ```
> function unstyle(className, sty) {
> ```

Reading the docs, it says that the `deleteRule` method accepts an index. This index comes from the second parameter of `insertRule` which you are currently not using. That means all you need to do is start keeping track of the indexes.

In order to keep track of the indexes, class names, and CSS rules, simply create a look up table and use a counter for the indexes:

```
var ruleToIndexTable = {};
var indexCounter = 0;
```

Now, when you are styling a rule, simply add it to the table:

```
indexCounter++;
ruleToIndexTable[rule] = indexCounter;
```

Note that this will require you to compute the rule somehow, which are technically already doing in the earlier part of the `style` function:

> ```
> sheet.insertRule('.' + className + ' {' + sty + '}');
> ```

We'll be using this logic again later, so it'll be best to extract this into it's own function `computeRule(className, sty)` and have both your `style` and `unstyle` functions take the single `rule` as a parameter.

Then later, in your `unstyle` function, you can simply use the lookup table to find out which table to delete:

```
function unstyle(rule) {
    sheet.removeRule(ruleToIndexTable[rule]);
}
```

*This assumes that `unstyle` can access `sheet`, too, which it now should be able to so you don't have to get the `sheet` element over and over again (which is inefficient).*

With these changes, your code is much more efficient now. With the addition of this look-up table and the new use of the `removeRule` function, your code now runs in \$O(1)\$ time (I think).

Answer (score 3):

It would be much easier just to toggle a class on a common parent element (such as `body`).

Let's say the elements you want to style have the class `my-item`:

```
.my-item {
  border: 1px solid blue; /* style them anyway you like */
}
```

Use a descendant selector, to restyle those elements, when a different class is set on a parent element:

```
.someClass .my-item {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

Toggle a class on body:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="document.body.classList.toggle('someClass', this.checked);" />
```

*(Uses classList. For support see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/classList or use jQuery's `.toggle()`.)*

Comment: I considered the common element method you suggest -- maybe I will use this. Thanks for bringing up toggle, I didn't know about that!

Answer (score 1):

I think you over-complicate the thing with toggling css rules. The whole thing can be done in 3 easy steps:

1. Add classes for selectors (e.g. `tgl-dash-border`) or do not add them if you want some css property to be toggled equally for all elements of a type (e.g. `input`)
2. Add listeners that would toggle corresponding class (e.g. `dash-border`)
3. Add css rules like `.dash-border {border: 1px #a00 dashed;}`.

This would do the work. And no need to toss stylesheets on the fly.